# How can I send password to user mail in Grails?

Tags: email, grails, authentication, forgot-password

I am new to Grails, I have login form for my app for which I have not used spring-security-plugin. Now I want to have a link in login form called forgot password which will retrieve it from database, but my problem is how to send it to that user mail id.

Answer (score 2):

Please, please, please - **never ever store your user's passwords in your database**.

If you understand and accept that you should never email users their password (or even store it in the database) you will find some useful resources on sending emails from your grails application below.

On sending emails from Grails read [this page](http://www.grails.org/Mail+from+Grails).

Answer (score 0):

Rather than sending them their password (which would require storing them unencrypted which is an incredibly bad idea) you should provide them a workflow where they can reset their password. Collect their email at signup, then send them a link to a page where they change the value. The [Spring Security UI](http://grails.org/plugin/spring-security-ui) plugin has support for this - see section "6 Forgot Password" in [the documentation](http://burtbeckwith.github.com/grails-spring-security-ui/docs/manual/index.html).

If you don't want to use the whole UI plugin, feel free to just use that code and workflow in your application.